# Dropdown menu broken on IE9

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

I am building a website from a bought theme, and in FF and in Chrome it looks perfect.But,on IE9 in compatibility mode, i am having a big problem.
One menu item has dropdown, and on IE, that dropdown menu is moved bellow the next menu item, and it is very hard to click o it.I tried "playing" around with CSS navigation and menu setting, but no luck...
Can anyone help:

```
/* Mainmenu Styling */
#mainmenu{
width:680px;
margin:1px 0px 0px 0px;
float:left;
}
.navigation{
width:630px;
margin-top:38px;
padding-left:160px;
float:left;
list-style-type:none;
 }
.navigation ul{
margin:0px; 
padding:0px; 
list-style-type:none; 
position:left;
clear:both; 
}
.navigation li{ 
list-style-type:none; 
padding:0px; 
margin:0px; 
float:left;
z-index:100; 
position:relative;
}
.navigation li a{
font-size:16px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#a7a6a6; 
display:block; 
padding:10px 30px 16px 8px;
float:left;
z-index:100; 
margin-right:0px;
 }
 .navigation li.current a, .navigation li a:hover, .navigation li.current li a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
color: #d23a3b; 
 }
.navigation li.current li a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#a7a6a6;
}
.navigation li li{
margin:0 0 0px 0px;
padding:0px;
position:relative;
z-index:100;    
}
.navigation ul{
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:45px;
width:159px;
padding-bottom:5px;
z-index:100;    
background-color:#fafafa;
border-top:none;
border-bottom:1px solid #d3d3d3;
border-left:1px solid #d3d3d3;
border-right:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.navigation li ul a{
width:109px;
height:auto;
float:left;
padding:0px 15px 8px 15px;
font-size:14px;
color:#a7a6a6;
line-height:24px;
z-index:100;
text-decoration:none;
```

}

Link is : http://goo.gl/LHDtg

Comment: Perhaps you have the same problem as [noted here](http://blog.ninanet.com/2011/04/29/cufon-and-ie9) (Cufon and  IE9 problems)?

Comment: check my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where...

Comment: IE compatibility mode gives me nightmares.

Comment: Dear without seeing how can i check the values and css.. can you show me the demo of new issue.

Answer (score 0):

try the below css for desired IE version

```
.navigation ul {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border-color: -moz-use-text-color #D3D3D3 #D3D3D3;
    border-style: none solid solid;
    border-width: medium 1px 1px;
    display: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px; /* in your website it is 45px but for IE i just tried 85px which work fine*/
    width: 159px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

see image for demo: I tried it in IE8

[image]

Comment: Happy, thanks :) I tried it, and it looks better, but now the dropdown has moved on the right (far right) :) Any other suggestion?

Comment: ohh new issue but dear without seeing how can i check the values and css.. can you show me the demo.